# Deleting files with Powershell recursively

Tags: powershell, recursion, powershell-2.0

I got somehow a weird issue, I am trying to use a process to automate the deletion of files from a folder and also child folders, I am trying to delete only files older than 7 days.

My code works but it deletes files that are under 7 days when going recursively into child items. . .anyone could lend a hand here? I just need to delete in each folder/sub-folder the files older than 7 days.

```
Param (
    [string]$Source = "C:\Users\Loredanes\Downloads\",
    [string]$Days = "1"
)


$Files = Get-ChildItem $Source -Recurse | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).addminutes(-$($Days)) }

$Files | Remove-Item -Force

if ($Files.count -gt 0)
{
    $Folders = @()
    ForEach ($Folder in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse -Directory))
    {
        $Folders += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Object = $Folder
            Depth = ($Folder.FullName.Split("\")).Count
        }
    }

    $Folders = $Folders | Sort Depth -Descending
    ForEach ($Folder in $Folders)
    {   
        If ($Folder.Object.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0)
        {
            Write-Host "Removing Folder: $($Folder)"
            Remove-Item -Path $Folder.Object.FullName -Force
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host "No Empty folders found after removing files older than $($Days) days."
}
```

Comment: These two makes no sense if you want to delete files older than 7 days. `[string]$Days = "1"`
`$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).addminutes(-$($Days))`. For instance, run this single line and you'll see what I mean. `$days = 1 ; Get-Date ; (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$($days))`

Comment: how should I modify this one? I know it's a bit obscure it's not written by me, still having a hard time following the lines there...makes clearly no sense, but I have to modify and adapt it for our purpose...

Comment: Well, instead of deleting all files older than 7 days from whenever the script is run, you delete all files older than 1 minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
$source = 'D:\Test'
$days   = 7

    # Remove Files
    Get-ChildItem $Source -Recurse | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$($days)) } | % { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force }

    # Remove empty directories
    Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.GetFiles("*.*").Count -le 0 } | % { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force }
```

Comment: Hey thanks, will test a 7 day period to validate everything, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are happy with, please mark as answer. Thanks.